# No hash key condition is applicable to the specified index

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to query from dynamoDB using a query expression with index name and defined `secondryGlobalIndex` in object.

But response is

> Illegal query expression: No hash key condition is applicable to the
>   specified index

code that I am using

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression()
            .withHashKeyValues(valueObject)
            .withIndexName("postID-commentTime-index")
            .withConsistentRead(false);



    try {
        PaginatedQueryList<ValueObject> result = 
(PaginatedQueryList) mapper.query(valueObjectClass, queryExpression);
```

Comment: You may want to see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963661/android-aws-querying-secondary-index-using-dynamodbmapper)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the hashkey schema for "postID-commentTime-index" is and example values of the corresponding valueObject?  Are you sure you have specified the indexHash using the DynamoDBIndexHashKey annotation.  And just as one more thought, looking at the doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/dynamodbv2/dynamodbmapper/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html#setHashKeyValues(T) Note 1: Currently the DynamoDBMapper supports only one value per hash key. Note 2: Currently the Amazon DynamoDB supports only one hash key per table/index.

Comment: did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Key conditions when querying an index pertain to the schema of the index and not of the base table. Make sure the key condition you are passing into the query is for the index and not the base table.